# Gaussian Mixture Model clustering in sparklyr

Tags: r, k-means, apache-spark-mllib, sparklyr, gmm

I'm trying to cluster my data using Gaussian Mixture Model in sparklyr:

```
ml_gaussian_mixture(formula= ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5, k = 5)
```

However, calling this function doesn't return a metric to evaluate the number of clusters as `ml_kmeans()` does (this function returns WSSSE).
Is there a way to get the Silhouette score or BIC for `ml_gaussian_mixture()` in sparklyr ?

Answer (score 0):

With

```
gmm_model <- ml_gaussian_mixture(iris_tbl, Species ~ .)
```

you can get the log-likelihood as

```
gmm_model$summary$log_likelihood
```

Which you can then use to get BIC or AIC.

I'm sure there must be a way to get it directly though. But if not, you may calculate BIC as

```
log(n) + k-1 + k * p + k * p * (p-1) / 2 - 2 * gmm_model$summary$log_likelihood
```

Where `n` - number of samples, `k` - number of clusters, `p`- number of variables. 
In above, the `k-1 + k * p + k * p * (p-1) / 2` is the number of free-parameters in a Gaussian mixture model (with unristricted co-variance matrices)

---

Example:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, iris, name = "iris_tbl", overwrite = TRUE)
gmm_model <- ml_gaussian_mixture(iris_tbl, Species ~ .)

gmm_model$summary$log_likelihood
#[1] -294.1398
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I get null when calling gmm_model$summary$log_likelihood.

Comment: See the example in the edit. It is possible you aren't getting a fit.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you went with this.

Comment: I'm getting a fit but still retrieving NULL when calling gmm_model$summary$log_likelihood.

Comment: See if the example I have given works. If so, then it is likely the problem related to your data.

Comment: With mixture models, you are likely to get some values for model parameters even if there wasn't a good fit: difficult to calculate inverse covariance matrix, etc. If it is possible to share a version of the data you use, maybe consider asking a different question to reslove that.